# Lag function bringing back random number for the first top row

Tags: sql, sql-server, lag

```
LAG (RegisterReading,1) OVER (PARTITION BY Mpancore ORDER BY meterserialnumber, MeterRegisterId) as LagFunc
```

Anyone please help.
Thanks

hello everyone, I have updated the report with all the keys added to the report,
i have used it against the `met_reg_read` and `mpan` as a combination partition but it doesnt seem to get the previous one for certain ones like `557` in the `lag func` and `lag test`.

lagtestlooks like this

```
LAG (d.RegisterReading,1,0) over (partition by Mpan, met_reg_read order by d.met_reg_read )
```

`lagfunc` without the default 0

link to new output

Answer (score 7):

This isn't a *random* value.  It is a value that appears somewhere with the same `Mpancore` value.  In this case, it is the last value.

The problem you are facing is that the `order by` clause has two keys, and these keys have duplicate values.  Hence, the ordering of keys with the same value is *arbitrary* or *indeterminate* (but not *random*, which has other implications).

I am not sure what you want to do, but I strongly recommend having a unique set of keys (so the sort is stable).  I think you can do this by including `RegisterReading`:

```
LAG(RegisterReading, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY Mpancore
                              ORDER BY meterserialnumber, MeterRegisterId, ReadingDateAndTime
                             ) as LagFunc
```

This still isn't perfect because there are still `NULL` values with duplicates.

Comment: Thank you Gordon, this has worked for that particular PMancore, but when I run it against a diffrent sample i get the same issue again. Is there any way around this by using the key's i have provided in the example so that it can work for every PMancore? Thank you

Comment: @abs786123 - Deterministic results require set of fields that can *uniquely* identify each row.  Those fields can then be used in the `PARTITION BY` and `ORDER BY`.  In your example data, that's not possible; even when you specify all 5 fields there are multiple rows that have the same values.  The very best you're going to get *(for the data you have shown)* is something like `PARTITION BY MpanCore, MeterIDSerialNumber, MeterRegisterID ORDER BY ReadDateAndTime, RegisterReading`.  If you have more fields to use, or want different results, I recommend you update your question with more details.

Comment: Hi I have updated the results to bring all unique keys, there is still the issue of it appearing with 557 when this was not in the register reading. I tried all sorts of different combination of partition and order by but it still comes up with showing something other then that. I have used the unique key met_reg_read thinking this would have solved it but it hasn't. Any sort of help will be appreciated thank you

Comment: My suggestion would be to put an order by clause of `<partitioning keys from the over clause>, <ordering keys from the over clause>` on the query to help you see the pattern.